# JS localeCompare acts weirdly

Tags: javascript, sorting, localization, internationalization

In Latvian, the letter "ā" comes immediately after the letter "a". The following strings are thus sorted correctly alphabetically:

> a, anna, ā, ābols

JS seems to think otherwise, however:
[image]

It does agree that "ā" comes after "a", but it also seems to think that "ā" comes before "anna", even though "anna" begins with a normal "a".

Any ideas why this happens?